# drupal hook_theme()

Tags: drupal

how to name the arguments's key in hook_theme,

eg:

```
     function user_theme() {
   return array(
    'user_picture' => array(
  'arguments' => array('account' => NULL),
  'template' => 'user-picture',
   ),
    'user_profile' => array(
  'arguments' => array('account' => NULL),
  'template' => 'user-profile',
  'file' => 'user.pages.inc',
    ),
 'user_list' => array('arguments' => array('users' => NULL, 'title' => NULL),),
     );
}
```

why the arguments array's key is  "account" ,"users" "title", how to get them. could i named them in other stuff. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use whatever you want, just like you can when you define a function like this:

```
<?php
function yourfunction($whatever, $you, $want) {

}
?>
```

The only thing that matters both for function definitions and theme arguments is the order (in D6, not anymore in D7) in which they are defined.